# Spring MVC, MySQL and UTF-8

Tags: mysql, spring, utf-8, blob

I have a problem with UTF-8. I use Spring MVC and MySQL.

In Spring, I have configured web.xml with:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and in my bean datasource I have:

```
 <bean id="dataSource"
    class="it.roundtable.db.manager.CustomDataSource" init-method="init">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

where CustomDataSource is:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

public class CustomDataSource extends BasicDataSource {

private void init() {
    addConnectionProperty("useUnicode", "true");
    addConnectionProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
}
```

}

In the my layout page I have:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" charset="utf8" >
```

In MySQL I have:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'colla%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and in my.cnf:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set=utf8
....
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-client=utf8
skip-external-locking
....
```

Now when I wrote in a form a phrase like this:

```
This is a prove: àèìòù
```

in Spring controller I print in the log:

```
...
logger.info("text --> " + text);
...
```

and the result printed in eclipse console is correct.

Then i save my text in a table in mysql with the data source and if I connect to mysql with the bash, I can read the correct text saved in my table.
In the next step, a spring controller retrive the data from mysql with a query, but I can look from the logger (eclipse console) that the letter "àèìòù" are wrong encoded:

```
This is a prove: �����
```

so the result in my web page is the same.
Can you help me please?

---

I have found the error: the type I used to save the text was BLOB, now I use the type TEXT and everything works perfectly.
Sorry!

Answer (score 17):

Make sure your JDBC connection is using UTF8 as well.   For example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/some_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

> For example, to use 4-byte UTF-8 character sets with Connector/J, configure the MySQL server with character_set_server=utf8mb4, and leave characterEncoding out of the Connector/J connection string. Connector/J will then autodetect the UTF-8 setting.
>
> To override the automatically detected encoding on the client side, use the characterEncoding property in the URL used to connect to the server.

See [5.4 Using Character Sets and Unicode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html#idm140274810207344) for more info.

Comment: Thx, but the problem remain, my properties: jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/roundtable?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8 
jdbc.username=*******
jdbc.password=*******

Comment: what happens if you set a breakpoint and look at the string value in the debugger?

Comment: What string value? The problem is when spring retrieve data from mysql, in fact, when I print to video data received from a query with accented letters, these  characters are wrong.

Comment: Try running this for the table that is storing the data: alter table  xxxx convert to character set 'utf8' collate 'utf8_general_ci';

Answer (score 0):

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/some_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

This is right，but maybe you need lowercase letters "utf-8".
like this

```
 jdbc:mysql://localhost/some_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

if your db deploy in Linux,the system are case sensitive